# Java, How can I find a pattern in a File and read the whole line?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, findinfiles, pattern-finding

I want to find a special charsequence in a file and I want to read the whole line where the occurrences are.

The following code just checks the first line and fetchess this ( the first ) line. 
How can I fix it?

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
   String output = "";

    output = output + scanner.findInLine(pattern) + scanner.next();
```

pattern and file are parameters

Comment: And what do you want to do with the result? Collect them in a list, something else?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER** according to the comments on this very answer

In fact, what is used is [Scanner#findWithHorizon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon-java.lang.String-int-), which in fact calls the `Pattern#compile` method with a set of flags ([Pattern#compile(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-)).

The result seems to be applying this pattern over and over again in the input text over lines of a file; and this supposes of course that a pattern cannot match multiple lines at once.

Therefore:

```
public static final String findInFile(final Path file, final String pattern, 
    final int flags)
    throws IOException
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, flags);

    String line;
    Matcher m;

    try (
        final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
    ) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            m = p.matcher(line);
            while (m.find())
                sb.append(m.group());
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

For completeness I should add that I have developed some time ago a package which allows a text file of arbitrary length to be read as a `CharSequence` and which can be used to great effect here: https://github.com/fge/largetext. It would work beautifully here since a `Matcher` matches against a `CharSequence`, not a `String`. But this package needs some love.

---

One example returning a `List` of matching strings in a file can be:

```
private static List<String> findLines(final Path path, final String pattern)
    throws IOException
{
    final Predicate<String> predicate = Pattern.compile(pattern).asPredicate();

    try (
        final Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
    ) {
        return stream.filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, uh, if you don't define your problem more precisely, there is little with can be done

Comment: yes, sorry! But i didnt know how I can explain my problem.

Comment: This is an effort you should commit to when asking a question :) Step back, think about the problem again, provide your own solution, explain why this solution does not do what you want... This is the secret of a good question :)